# won't boot to external hdd version of ubuntu. only boots to internalhdd version on startup

Tags: boot

Have installed a second ubuntu 13.1 on an external hard drive. Have changed BIOS to open usb first. I have same version of 13.1 on my internal hard drive. on startup, I get the internal hard drive version. Can't access the external hard drive version. Need some help

Comment: How did you installed the USB one?

Answer (score 0):

Some BIOS require to set USB-HDD instead of just USB.
Also, you should check boot device priority to confirm that the 1st hdd you are booting is the USB one.